# EF Code First DropCreateDatabaseAlways not executed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a test application where I would like to drop and recreate database every time I run the application. This is my context class:

```
public class MySolutionContext : DbContext
{
    public MySolutionContext()
        : base("MySolution")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MySolutionContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways());
    }

    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderITems { get; set; }


    public void Seed(MySolutionContext context)
    {

        var order1 = new Order
        {
            Archive = false,
            CompletionDate = DateTime.Now,
            Person = "Bartosz"
        };
        var order2 = new Order
        {
            Archive = false,
            CompletionDate = DateTime.Now,
            Person = "Anna"
        };
        context.Orders.Add(order1);
        context.Orders.Add(order2);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public class DropCreateDatabaseAlways : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MySolutionContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(MySolutionContext context)
        {
            context.Seed(context);
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the application for the first time, Seed method is executed and database gets created. However, when I stop and rerun the application, Seed method is not firing at all and previously created database is being used. Why does it happen? What am I missing in my code?

Comment: Why are you so sure that the database is not re-created? How are you testing it?

Comment: I am adding new order via the interface

Comment: Is it a web app? If so, make sure that the server (IIS / IIS Express) really stops between executions.

Comment: I use LocalDB, does it change anything?

Comment: I use Local IIS Web server and run the application from VS under DEBUG mode

Comment: Stop the IIS server (I suppose is IIS express). If so, you have an icon in the notification area (of Windows) that allows you to stop it. It doesn't matter if it's LocalDB or a full-fledged SQL server.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Does the code look ok to you?

Comment: I've got migrations switched on, does it matter? http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1689

Comment: I see one strange thing: you implemented the `Seed` method on the DbContext. It doesn't belong there, it belongs on the Initializer class. Now you are feeding `MySolutionContext`an instance of itself in its `Seed` method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is that migration is activated in your current project. Related to this article (http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1689), it's not possible to use migration **AND** "DropCreateDatabaseAlways" as the initializer at the same time.

If you want to use migration and "DropCreateDatabaseAlways" (which is completely useless, except from testing maybe), you'll have to write a own Init() method, which deletes and creates your database at every application start.

```
Database.Delete();
Database.Create();
```

But if you deactivate migration, you can use the initalizer "DropCreateDatabaseAlways".

If the problem is still there without migration here are some hints how to solve this kind of problem:

The Initializer is only executed if you are using the instance of the database or if the database doesn't exist. The seed method is part of your Initializer, so it doesn't get executed as well. To fix this problem you can "work" with the database by accessing part of the data like:

```
context.Set<Entity>.Count();
```

or any other method which works with the database.

Another solution is to force the database to call the Initializer:

```
Database.Initialize(true/false);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're right on some questions, but, to be more exact, Database.Initialize runs when you use a DbContext instance for the first time. Or when you invoke it directly. I.e. it's true that you need to init the DB in one of these two ways. But, if you have a "DropCreateDatabaseAlways" it will always delete and re-create the DB. If it doesn't it must have something to do with migrations (but I think, it doesn't). It would be interesting if you could check with a proof of concept if there is some interaction with Migrations. I doubt it. If you update your answer, and leave a comment I'll upvote.

Comment: @JotaBe Thx for your comment, just to be sure, you think that Migration has nothing to do with the problem, that the Initializer does not execute? If this is your question, have you read the article inside my answer? There the ET Team is saying that Migration IS a problem when using "DropCreateDatabaseAlways", and I recognized it by myself in my project as well. I hope I understood your question right.

Comment: Yes, that's my question and it's an excellent answer, but cannot be understand at once: there is an explanation of something with an edit and an update, and a link to an external resource, whose content is unknown unless you open it. It's a pity that your good answer is useless because of these details. Don't worry about fully rewriting it, or copying+pastying the content of the linked article, or a part of it, and explain briefly what's inside and tell the reader to open it for details. That would make it an excellent answer. Please, edit it again, "without fear of changing it all". Good job!

Comment: @JotaBe Thx for your feedback, I'll improve my answer! At first the answer was a reply to Bartosz' last comment under his question, that's why it's so confusing. Now I'll improve the answer, so that everybody can understand it. Thx again!

Answer (score 2):

In a test project, I also needed to drop the database and recreate everything each time I start the tests.

Simply adding the following line was not enough:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());
```

I tweaked it with this :

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApsContext>());

using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    context.Database.Delete();
}
```

It's important to know that, if migration is enabled, you need to actually call the database to create the schema. I simply call an entity trying to find something with Id = 0 (so it returns nothing).